# Why is there no information output from the console after two seconds --- Rxjava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

```
public class RxJavaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("timer: accept " + aLong);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Why is there no information output from the console after two seconds?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `timer` changes the scheduler of your downstream so it is executed in parallel to the rest of your main function. This means that the main function is free to finish and, with it, the entire program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `timer` operator is executed in a different Thread (in the computation thread pool) and your `main` thread is exited just after calling the subscribe and shutdowns the VM.

Yo have different solutions for this.

1. Add a `Thread.sleep(value > 2000)` after your `subscribe`
2. Call `blockingSubscribe` instead of `subscribe`. The current thread (main) blocks until the upstream terminates
3. Change the time scheduler to trampoline :

```java
    Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.trampoline())
```

From the documentation

> The default implementation's {@link
>   Scheduler#scheduleDirect(Runnable)} methods execute the tasks on the
>   current thread without any queueing and the timed overloads use
>   blocking sleep as well.