# RXJava Observable onNext emitted on different threads

Tags: java, rx-java

If i try to emit onNext on different thread's, on subscribing it dosent catch the stream on next elements.

```
public static Observable<Student> getStudents()
{
    return Observable.create(e -> {

          for(int i : Arrays.asList(1,2,3))
          {
              Thread t = new Thread(() -> {

                  e.onNext(new Student("anirba", i));

              });
              t.start();
          }
          e.onComplete();
    });
}
```

On sunbscribing to this observable i dont get any response`enter code here`

```
Observable<Student> observer = getStudents();

    observer.subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Comment: As the onNext() is called from the separate thread, which the subscribe is executed. the thread might not get executed. That's why you are not getting the output.

Comment: Try adding wait or sleep on the main thread, that will give time for child thread to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating three threads inside the create method and each is adding an object of Student to stream. The reason why you are not getting any output is all these three threads will be running independently and based on thread scheduler it will be executed. In your case, the onComplete() method might get called before all these three threads add data into the Observable stream. and on-call of onComplete, the stream will be closed and no more data will be accepted by the stream. To make it work just to the below changes, it should work as you are expecting.

```
public static Observable<Student> getStudents() {
    return Observable.create(e -> {
          for(int i : Arrays.asList(1,2,3)) {
              Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                  e.onNext(new Student("anirba", i));
              });
              t.start();
          }
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          e.onComplete();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.concurrent.Executor` is the right API now for running tasks. To block the current thread you can use `CountDownLatch` and release it when all tasks are terminated.

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); // choose the right one

public Observable<Student> getStudents() {
    return Observable.<Student>create(emitter -> {
        List<Integer> source = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(source.size());

        source
                .forEach(i ->
                        executor.submit(() -> {
                            emitter.onNext(new Student("anirba", i));
                            latch.countDown();
                        }));

        latch.await();
        emitter.onComplete();
    }).serialize();
}
```

And elsewhere don't forget to call `shutdown()` on the `executor`.

You may also add `serialize()` operator to avoid `onnext()` calls to overlap.

From the [contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) :

> Observables must issue notifications to observers serially (not in
> parallel). They may issue these notifications from different threads,
> but there must be a formal happens-before relationship between the
> notifications.

For the perpose of testing you can add `Thread.sleep(x)` to see your loggin. I've already answerd this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59009512/8325761)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
     getStudents()
             .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i));
    
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```